# Get query of autoinjection in case the entry is not found

Tags: entry, query, 404, element

Is there a way to get the element query which is/was executed by Craft to autoinject the corresponding entry into the template? (even if it fails)

I would like to catch it in case of a 404 to return a 410 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410) while the entry is soft-deleted and a 404 afterwards. In other words: I want to change the response code from 404 to 410 if I still find the entry in the trash.

Comment: i am not sure if what throws 404 in your code and you have control over it or not but it seems there is a EVENT_BEFORE_SEND and maybe you can set status code this way https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3890#issuecomment-467234580